# Installing phpmyadmin with home-brew

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin

I have tried to install and configure phpmyadmin using home-brew. To install I used the commands `brew install phpmyadmin` and this is the summary of the message printed in the terminal.

```
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0-beta.1: 342 files, 50.3M, built in 7 minutes 29 seconds
==> Installing homebrew/php/phpmyadmin
==> Downloading https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/archive/RELEASE_4_6_2.t
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/tar.gz/RE
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Caveats
Note that this formula will NOT install mysql. It is not
required since you might want to get connected to a remote
database server.

Webserver configuration example (add this at the end of
your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for instance) :
  Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
  <Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
Then, open http://localhost/phpmyadmin

More documentation : file:///usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.6.2/share/phpmyadmin/doc/

Configuration has been copied to /usr/local/etc/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php
Don't forget to:
  - change your secret blowfish
  - uncomment the configuration lines (pma, pmapass ...)

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.6.2: 2,256 files, 63.2M, built in 39 seconds
```

I followed the instruction at the terminal output, despite this when I type into the url http://localhost/phpmyadmin into safari I still end up with the error message, `Safari can't open the page "localhost/phpmyadmin" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost"`. I think it's possible that I have set the cookie configuration correctly in the phpmyadmin.config.in.php file but not sure how I can correct this.

Answer (score 17):

I found that the instructions are not complete, you also have to:

1. Remove the '#' comment at the beginning in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for LoadModule php5_module:

   ```
   LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
   ```
2. Edit the DirectoryIndex settings in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to:

   ```
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html home.pl index.cgi
   ```
3. Save the file...
4. Start Apache Webserver in Terminal application:

   ```
   sudo apachectl start
   ```

   If it's already started, it will show you a message: "service already loaded", in this case run:

   ```
   sudo apachectl restart
   ```
5. Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Wait for a bit then refresh the page several times (maybe a previous state was cached or the service is not started yet..)

Comment: It works for me! In my case, the secret blowfish and uncomment the configuration lines are not necessary. Thanks Champ!

Comment: For php7: `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

Comment: Thanks, It works for me with php7 too

Answer (score 5):

I think you missed the first part as explained by balazs630.. here is the same:

==> php
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
    /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/

To have launchd start php now and restart at login:
  brew services start php
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  php-fpm

==> phpmyadmin
To enable phpMyAdmin in Apache, add the following to httpd.conf and
restart Apache:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Then open http://localhost/phpmyadmin