# Installing phpmyadmin with homebrew and nginx

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I develop Laravel based websites on my MacBook using Valet. Right now I'm working from home and I can't access the database at work so I'm trying to install PHPMyAdmin using Homebrew so I can import a database dump and work locally as well.
I think my question is similar to this question: [Installing phpmyadmin with home-brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543587/installing-phpmyadmin-with-home-brew)  except I'm using nginx.
I did get the output after installing:

```
==> Installing phpmyadmin from homebrew/php
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-php/phpmyadmin-4.7.4.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/44/44d9e5789593f86499263496d6e901ecb9ce1b999e76ee4842268ef35d547c9f?__gda__=exp=1505301978~hmac=b16623e81ca8559fcd18e54c17dee0a6f42cfcd85892fd6f43f8f0dd14e4746c&response-content-disposition=
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring phpmyadmin-4.7.4.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Note that this formula will NOT install mysql. It is not
required since you might want to get connected to a remote
database server.

Webserver configuration example (add this at the end of
your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for instance) :
  Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
  <Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
Then, open http://localhost/phpmyadmin

More documentation : file:///usr/local/opt/phpmyadmin/share/phpmyadmin/doc/

Configuration has been copied to /usr/local/etc/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php
Don't forget to:
  - change your secret blowfish
  - uncomment the configuration lines (pma, pmapass ...)

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.7.4: 2,345 files, 34.0MB
```

How do I enabled access to phpmyadmin with nginx? 
http://localhost/phpmyadmin returns a 404

In case you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Did you update the nginx config? Also did you run `php-fpm` ? See this https://coderwall.com/p/lbaf6q/installing-php-5-4-mysql-phpmyadmin-and-nginx-on-mac-using-homebrew

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I don't think I have updated the nginx config.
I tried following the steps in the article you linked to, but I can't find the `listen` line in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php-fpm.conf`.

Comment: You need to edit it in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php-fpm.d/www.conf`. Be default it uses `127.0.0.1:9000`. if you are specific about using socket files then you would need to change this file, else you can use `127.0.0.1:9000` in in your nginx config instead of the socket

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for that.
I just managed to get it to work using Laravel Valet though, so I don't have to edit anything for sockets etc. With Valet I can navigate to `http://phpmyadmin.dev` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with a work-around.
Turned out there were more problems with the configuration of my MacBook so I performed a fresh install and started from scratch.

Since I use Laravel and Laravel Valet for the development of websites, I had to install composer first.
Then I installed Valet using the descriptions in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet#installation) using Homebrew.
After that I followed the steps in [the guide](https://coderwall.com/p/lbaf6q/installing-php-5-4-mysql-phpmyadmin-and-nginx-on-mac-using-homebrew) @Tarun Lalwani linked to up to the PHP FPM section.

Then I downloaded the latest version of [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) manually, renamed the exttracted folder to phpMyAdmin and moved it to my Valet park directory.
Navigating to http://phpmyadmin.dev now correctly displays phpMyAdmin and it works perfectly.

Comment: Confirming that this still works in 2022 with Laravel Valet. Just download the latest phpMyAdmin, unzip to where you want it, valet link it and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

ln -sfv /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin /Projects/phpmyadmin

Projects is path localhost